# jQuery - known class of child: find next descendent of parent in top (from parent ID)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been searching a lot for this, without any solution so far. As you might also have seen the topic title might be a little hard to interpret and that's because I'm not quite sure how to explain it shortly.

**The problem**
Looking at the HTML below, I know the class of the last element called "active" and this element is chosen dynamically in jQuery, based on which site the visitor is on currently - i.e. different elements has this class depending on the site. On another site the `li` with class `first-sub-li` could have the class `active` (or for that matter the `li` with class `first`). This class is, as said, added dynamically based on the site with jquery. From here on I wish to identify the parent of the element with `active` which is a direct descendent of `top-parent` and add a class called `active-parent` to this. I.e. in the case below i wish to add the `active-parent` class to the `li` with class `second`.

**EDIT:** Please note that the "depth" of the list can vary, therefore also requiring a "dynamic" approach to picking out the parent. I completely forgot this in the initial writing.

```
<ul id="top-parent">
<li class="first">
<ul class="first-sub-ul">
<li class="first-sub-li"></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="second">
<ul class="second-sub-ul">
<li class="second-sub-li">
<ul class="second-sub-sub-ul">
<li class="second-sub-sub-li active"></li>           <!-- Here -->
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

So far I've tried the following jQuery without succes as it doesn't identify it.

**EDIT 2:** This actually **does** work, but initially it didn't as it apparently was called before the class was loaded, despite appearing later in the javascript document. Wrapping it in a `$(window).on("load", function()` solves the problem as shown below.

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
$(".active").closest("#top-parent > li").addClass("active-parent");
});
```

The original code was just `$(".active").closest("#top-parent > li").addClass("active-parent");`

Comment: _"as I can't see how the browser should be able to identify which li is meant"_ - throw in a little https://api.jquery.com/has/ to select only those LI that have a descendant with class `active` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start traversing up with [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/), it will excluding the self `li`.

```
$(".active").parent().closest("li").addClass("active-parent");
```

---

You can use [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```
$('#top-parent > li:has(.active)').addClass("active-parent");
```

```js
$('#top-parent > li:has(.active)').addClass("active-parent");
```

```css
.active-parent {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="top-parent">
  <li class="first">
    <ul class="first-sub-ul">
      <li class="first-sub-li"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="second">
    <ul class="second-sub-ul">
      <li class="second-sub-li">
        <ul class="second-sub-sub-ul">
          <li class="second-sub-sub-li active"></li>
          <!-- Here -->
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ah my goodness, i totally forgot to add that the "length/depth" of the lists differ, meaning that the `second` list can be another level "deeper" than the others. I will add this asap!

Comment: Great, it works! However it actually seems that the code i initially used  works as well - it just didn't work at the beginning as it was called before the class was added (even though it came later in the actual document.. no idea why). Adding a `.on("load", function...` actually solved it and I only did that by accident. I will mark this as correct though as it surely solved the problem and was very close to my original wish for this appliance :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for. Find all `li` which are direct descendants of `topmost-parent`  and filter that for the one which has a child `.active`. Apply the class.

```js
$('#top-parent > li').filter(function(e){
   return $(this).find('.active').length>0;
}).addClass("active-parent");
```

```css
.active-parent{background-color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="top-parent">
  <li class="first">
    <ul class="first-sub-ul">
      <li class="first-sub-li">1.1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="second">
    <ul class="second-sub-ul">
      <li class="second-sub-li active">2.1</li>           <!-- Here -->
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```